# LoginToBoggan + Don't use set password mail

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

I would like to give my user the opportunity to register and login with username AND email.

Therefore I installed the module [LoginToBoggan](https://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) where you can enable that users can login using their e-mail address.

When you want users to set their password at registration you need to check the checkbox **Set password**. But when you do this you also get a mail to set your password (can only be used once).

But I don't want that. I just want them to register with email/username and directly login in without getting ANY email. I fire a rule to send a mail after I created an invoice so I don't want the drupal account emails.

But I didn't found out how I can simply do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the same type of setup as the one you describe:

- Register and login with username and email.
- Login using the email address.
- User sets password upon registration (i.e. no email confirmation required).

I've found that the process where user receives a one-time link to set password is a huge stumbling block in the registration process.

Drupal let set up the site to have user sets password upon registration (Uncheck "Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account" on *Administration » Configuration » People » Account settings*).

However, I do *not* use [LoginToBoggan](https://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) to allow the users to login using the email address.

Instead, I use [Realname Reg](https://drupal.org/sandbox/gisleh/1951414).  Please note that this is a sandbox project, but it is actively maintaned (by me), and it has been tuned specifically for the use case you describe.  I've used it on a dozen production sites for about a year with no issues.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the change password at registration mail after installing your module. What could be the problem of this?

Comment: I did, but I'm still getting the mail. I register, I get logged in but I'm stil getting set password email

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this.  Btw, that setting is Drupal core - it has nothing to do with my module.  At my sites, it works as intended.  It must be some other module you've got installed that interferes with it.  I suggest you set up a clean install of Drupal, and then enables this core feature and verfies that it works.  Then install my module and verify that it still works.  **LoginToBoggan** is the prime suspect for messig up this.  Make sure you fully uninstall it (not just disable it).

Comment: And could I set it directly in the code (just extra, maybe it works)

Comment: I've added this $conf['user_mail_register_no_approval_required_notify'] = FALSE; to my settings.php and now it works. Strange ..

Comment: The link to your sandbox project does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem a few days ago, I was using this logintoboggan module but didn't want my user to confirm emails, just register with password and login as well, so what I did is to remove the 'non-authenticate' user role from the user and add 'authenticate' role when the user login for the first time.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user_login().
 */
function mymodule_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  if (in_array('non authenticated user', $account->roles)) {
    // remove non-auth role from user object.
    _remove_role_from_user($uid, 'non authenticated user');
    // Add auth role to user object.
    _add_role_to_user($uid, 'authenticated user');
  }
}

function _add_role_to_user($user, $role_name) {

  // For convenience, we'll allow user ids as well as full user objects.
  if (is_numeric($user)) {
    $user = user_load($user);
  }
  // If the user doesn't already have the role, add the role to that user.
  $key = array_search($role_name, $user->roles);
  if ($key == FALSE) {
    // Get the rid from the roles table.
    $roles = user_roles(TRUE);
    $rid = array_search($role_name, $roles);
    if ($rid != FALSE) {
      $new_role[$rid] = $role_name;
      $all_roles = $user->roles + $new_role; // Add new role to existing roles.
      user_save($user, array('roles' => $all_roles));
    }
  }
}

function _remove_role_from_user($user, $role_name) {
  // For convenience, we'll allow user ids as well as full user objects.
  if (is_numeric($user)) {
    $user = user_load($user);
  }
  // Only remove the role if the user already has it.
  $key = array_search($role_name, $user->roles);
  if ($key == TRUE) {
    // Get the rid from the roles table.
    $roles = user_roles(TRUE);
    $rid = array_search($role_name, $roles);
    if ($rid != FALSE) {
      // Make a copy of the roles array, without the deleted one.
      $new_roles = array();
      foreach($user->roles as $id => $name) {
        if ($id != $rid) {
          $new_roles[$id] = $name;
        }
      }
      user_save($user, array('roles' => $new_roles));
    }
  }
}
```